# Code Always Executes after response is sent to the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

Here is the code I have an issue where If I don't set a timeout in the asyncCall function then the response is sent before the async code finishes hence I do not get the images from the **onlineBooksImages()**
function but including the timeout in the below code

```
  setTimeout(() => {


    if (onlineBook) {

        res.status(200).render("showBooks",
            {
                result: result,
                favourites: favourites,
                user: user,
                book: onlineBook

            });
    } 



}, 5000);
```

**delays the response from being sent hence I get the images how can I write the below code in order to remove the timeout which is longer than what would have been a faster load using asynchronous code**

```
var boos = []
var boos2 = []
var boos3 = []
var foo = {}
var foo2 = {}
var foo3 = {}

const onlineBook= await Books2.findById(req.params.id);
const Ebook = await Ebooks.findById(req.params.id);

 function onlineBooksImages() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {

            let temporaryVar = []
            onlineBook.allimages.forEach(element => {
                gfs.files.findOne({ _id: element }, (err, file) => {
                    if (!file || file.length === 0) {
                        return res.status(404).json({
                            err: "No file exist"
                        });
                    }
                    var u = []
                    u.push(onlineBook._id)
                    var img = []
                    img.push(file)
                    user.push(file)
                    foo3[u] = temporaryVar;
                    //console.log(user.length);
                });
            });
            boos3.push(foo3)

            resolve(boos3);
        }, 100);
    });
} 
  async function asyncCall() {
    console.log('calling');
    if (onlineBook) {
        var result = await onlineBooksImages();
    } else if (Ebook) {
        var result2 = await someOtherFunction();//notImportant

    } else {
        return res.status(404).render('error', { user });
    }
    setTimeout(() => {


        if (onlineBook) {

            res.status(200).render("showBooks",
                {
                    result: result,
                    favourites: favourites,
                    user: user,
                    book: onlineBook

                });
        } 



    }, 5000);

}
```

Comment: you're doing asynchronous operation inside a .forEach - that never works - you'll need to promisify the `gfs.files.findOne` call (unless it can already return a Promise) and use a regular for/for...of/for...in loop with async/await

Comment: Do you know how I can do that....

Comment: quick question ... should `(!file || file.length === 0)` cancel the whole process and just return the 404 status, even if another iteration may find (or a previous already found) a `file`?

Comment: oh, and this `var u = []
                    u.push(onlineBook._id)
                    foo3[u] = temporaryVar;` is an odd way to do `foo3(onlineBook._id) = temporaryVar;`

Comment: `(!file || file.length === 0)` yes but thinking of it right now that you mentioned it kind of a wrong choice

Comment: `var u = [] u.push(onlineBook._id) foo3[u] = temporaryVar;` now I see how silly this is after you pointed out the other way

Comment: I've added an answer - not convinced it solves all the issues - but should solve the asynchronous issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the answer ... there's some interesting code in here

```
  this code looks wrong on many levels

  var u = [];
  u.push(onlineBook._id);
  // snip
  foo3[u] = temporaryVar;
```

Now, lets say `onlineBook._id` === `"abc"`

Therefore `u === ['abc']`

So `foo3[u]` is the same as `foo3[u.toString()]` ... which would be `foo3['abc']`

So why not just `foo3[onlineBook._id] = temporaryVar;`

But even that looks strange, becuase every property in `foo3` will refer to the same array

e.g. if the book id's are 'abc', 'def' and 'ghi' then `foo3.abc`, `foo3.def` and `foo3.ghi` will be the exact same empty array!

ANyway, on to an answer, though I'm still confused about your "global" boos* and foo* variables - but lets just fix the problem you have:

```
function async onlineBooksImages() {
  let temporaryVar = [];
  for (let element of onlineBook.allimages) {
    try {
      const file = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        gfs.files.findOne({_id: element}, (err, file) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            temporaryVar.push(file);
            resolve(file);
        })
      });
      if (!file || file.length === 0) {
        return reject();
      }
      foo3[onlineBook._id] = temporaryVar;

    } catch(e) {
        // do nothing but catch the error
    }
  }
  if (Object.keys(foo3).length) {
    boos3.push(foo3);
    return boos3;
  } else {
    // reject if there were no images in any of allimages
    throw({status: 400, err: "No file exist"});
  }
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  try {
    if (onlineBook) {
      var result = await onlineBooksImages();
    } else if (Ebook) {
      var result2 = await someOtherFunction();//notImportant
    } else {
      return res.status(404).render('error', { user });
    }
    if (onlineBook) {
      res.status(200).render("showBooks", {
        result: result,
        favourites: favourites,
        user: user,
        book: onlineBook
      });
    } 
  } catch(e) {
      if (e.status && e.err) {
        res.status(e.status).json({
          err: e.err
        });
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes this solves the asynchronous issue any advice with dealing with promises and async code **THANK YOU**